# How can i get these Git commands to work?

Tags: git, github, command, project, git-bash

1. can anyone help me, I am not able to use git commands (config & add.)
   [SS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTaag.png)

As i was trying to upload my project to git hub, using git but i was unable to use these commands (config and add.) as its showing 'config' is not a git command. What is the problem here?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5586359 Text, please! http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode. [Edit] your question, copy/paste from the terminal and properly [format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) it as code. Images are not helpful, they're hard to read and hard to search. Badly formatted code is hard to read. Images are only good to show something non-textual (like colors, fonts, screen positions, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure you followed this steps:

1 git init
2 git config --global user.name example
3 git config --global user.email example@gmail.com
4 git add .
5 git status
6 git commit -m "example message"